# Value isn't passed to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am trying to pass a variable `userId` to my second page.

Here is the code piece I use to pass value to next page:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(key, value) {
    var userId = value.id_user;
    var stText = value.status_text;
    if (stText == "OK") {                  
        //if provide a valid username change the location 
        //to the specified page.
        window.location = "http://myurl.com/profile.php";
        window.location.href = "http://myurl.com/profile.php?userId=" + userId;
    }
});
```

But url looks like:

http://myurl.com/profile.php?userId=undefined

Comment: And that's because the value of `value.id_user` and therefore `userId` is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you show the data?

Comment: I have created a test, and it is working. The problem must be caused by the data where an object/map has the field `status_text` but not the field `id_user`.

Comment: @Barry $.post(signUpServiceUrl,{'api_key':apiKey,'api_secret':apiSecret,'username':userName,'email':email,'password':password},function(data){

Comment: var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(result.data, function(key, value){
     var userId = value.id_user;
     var stText = value.status_text;

Comment: We need to inspect the data returned from this call. Insert before the code shown in your question an `alert(data);` or `console.log(data);` so that you can visually inspect if data contains the field `id_user`.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work try this one,

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$.each(result.data, function(key, value) {
    var userId = value.id_user;
    var stText = value.status_text;
    if (stText == "OK") {                  
        //if provide a valid username change the location 
        //to the specified page.
        window.location = "http://myurl.com/profile.php";
        window.location.href = "http://myurl.com/profile.php?userId=" + userId;
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem. The script is correct, otherwise `(stText == "OK")` can not be evaluated to true and resulting in `http://myurl.com/profile.php?userId=undefined`.

Comment: check if userId has value?

Comment: if didnt redirect means if condition may fail

Comment: @soundhiraraj yes userId has value returned as the response.

Comment: @soundhiraraj when i alert the userId at first it will displays an alert box with undefined as content then displays the alert box with userId

Comment: could you give json data?

Comment: {"header":{"status":"200","status_text":"OK"},"data":{"id_user":"38"}}               This is the sample response

Comment: use like that '{"header":{"status":200,"status_text":"OK"}',"data":{"id_user":38}}';

Answer (score 0):

this may Work try this

```
var data='{"header":{"status":"200","status_text":"OK"},"data":{"id_user":"38"}}';
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(result.data, function(key, value) {
        var userId = value.id_user;
        var stText = value.status_text;
        if (stText == "OK") {                  
            //if provide a valid username change the location 
            //to the specified page.
           // window.location = "http://myurl.com/profile.php";
            window.location.href = "http://myurl.com/profile.php?userId=" + userId;
        }
    });
```